# Error to import Orange module in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, orange

I installed my orange from the official web site using the "Classic installer" that install python 3.6 together and all the libraries.But when I try to do a import Orange  from my python returns me **"ModuleNotFoundError"**.
I found a python.exe inside my Orange folder, there if I do a Orange import , works...
How I  can fix this problem with my python?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: In your terminal type "which python" and note the path.  Chances are the path returned won't match the path of the python executable in your "Orange" directory.  If you want to be able to import the Orange module, you will need to make sure you are using the correct python install.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I should type this in the cmd prompt ? because returned me an error...

Comment: Orange installed this python :[link]https://ibb.co/SJPX75C and this python I wont able to do an Orange import... but If I open the orange folder I am able... with python prompt

Comment: If you are using the python.exe within the orange folder, and you can import orange, then it sounds like everything is working correctly.  When you run a different install of python, it won't be able to import Orange, unless you install the module there as well.

Comment: but Orange dont install a python Shell ? and I didnt have any python in this machine before install orange...

Comment: I installed a new machine virtual and install again the  "Classic installer"  from orange website, an didnt work...

Answer (score 2):

When you install Orange using the installer, what you get is a base python installation (if one was not already found on your system) and a separate virtual environment with Orange and all the dependencies installed into it.

There should be a 'Orange Command Prompt' shortcut installed in the 'Start Menu'. That will open a Command Prompt with the proper environment activated so you can use python.exe, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to type this in your console.

```
 pip install Orange3
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... I tried but return me this error "python setup.py egg_info " failed with error code 1

Comment: @JRH Hope you had a uppercase O in Orange3 while running the command